# number instead of date string when writing xlsx file

Tags: python, libreoffice, xlsxwriter

In a LibreOffice xlsx cell, the value is like this: 01/13/2016.
When I am creating a new xlsx file using python2, then that 01/13/2016 is converting to 42461.

python code :

```
sheet1.write(row,col,sheet.cell(row,col).value) 
tab_matching = 0
for sheet_name in book.sheet_names():   

temp_sheet_name = sheet_name.lower()
if temp_sheet_name == tab_name: 
    tab_matching = 1

    sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
    temp_sheet_name = file_prefix+part_file_name+"_"+file_type+".xlsx"
    if os.path.exists(detail_path):
        xlsx_file_name = detail_path+"/"+temp_sheet_name
    else:
        xlsx_file_name = dirname+"/"+temp_sheet_name

    new_book = xlsxwriter.Workbook(xlsx_file_name)
    sheet1 = new_book.add_worksheet()


    for row in range(sheet.nrows):

        for col in range(sheet.ncols):  
            sheet1.write(row,col,sheet.cell(row,col).value)     

    new_book.close()
```

Could you tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Can you paste the code?

Comment: The cell is probably not formatted as a date.

Comment: Convert it to a string and then write the sting value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`42461` is the underlying date value for 04/01/2016.  To show the date instead of the number, specify a date format:

```
format1 = new_book.add_format({'num_format': 'mm/dd/yyyy'})
sheet1.write('B1', 42461, format1)  # 04/01/2016
sheet1.write('B2', 42382, format1)  # 01/13/2016
```

Documentation is at http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html.

Comment: Excellent.. Exactly I wanted this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today=datetime.datetime.now()
>>> today
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 27, 1, 7, 1, 909049)
>>> value=today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
'27/08/2016'
>>> sheet1.write(row,col,sheet.cell(row,col).value)
```

Comment: you copy paste from some other post.

Comment: If you knew that earlier, that there was another post, why did you ask the question when you knew the answer was there?

Comment: sorry this is not working. PLease read my post carefully. Dont waste time here.

Comment: Moreover, I wrote this code after running it in my browser, verifying it, etc.